# Decimal amount from UITextField to Core Data integer field

Tags: core-data, uitextfield

I have a UITextField in my app that accepts decimal amounts for prices (i.e., 123.45).  This field is stored in Core Data as an integer.

The code I have that doesn't work is:

```
[self.managedObject setValue:[textField floatValue]*100 forKey:@"price"]
```

And I can't quite figure out how to make this work.  Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. the answer is `[[self managedObject] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:([textField floatValue]*100)] forKey:@"price"]`
2. You should be using NSDecimalNumber for currency as it handles decimals without floating point issues.

Comment: And use "Decimal" as the attribute type in your data model.